# Environment variables (process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT)

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

I'm starting with micro cloud foundry node applications. I have a newbie question, I'd like to solve. I have a simple code that creates a new node web server listening on port 3000. It works locally. When I upload it to my micro cloud foundry instance, I see that the listening port has changed process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT me. What is the reason? Can you upload an application and customize the listening port? thanksI'm starting with micro cloud foundry node applications. I have a newbie question, I'd like to solve. I have a simple code that creates a new node web server listening on port 3000. It works locally. When I upload it to my micro cloud foundry instance, I see that the listening port has changed process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT me. What is the reason? Can you upload an application and customize the listening port? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cloudfoundry runs your application in specific container OR execution environment (called DEA). DEA controls access to ports and services for each application. It provides you application execution port using environment variable VCAP_APP_PORT So that your application can use it. This is default and desired feature by cloudfoundry.